# Error 2 while building a project with Cordova (Phonegap)

Tags: android, linux, cordova, build

I recently installed cordova (phonegap), and am having such a difficult time getting it running on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04)

Whenever I try to build my project, I get this error :

```
[Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]
Error: /home/<my-name>/phone_project/workshop/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I researched this problem and try these different fixes :

- I set my PATH variable both to the tools and platform-tools in my adt-bundle.
- I set my ANT_HOME variable and didn't forget to add the ANT_HOME/bin in my PATH :
- I set my JAVA_HOME variable to java 1.7 jdk :

None of them worked for me.

Here is a copy of my ~/.bashrc file :

(...)

```
export PATH=~/phone_project/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools/:~/phone_projet/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/:/androicdd-sdks/platform-tools/:$PATH
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

Those are all the fixes I found, and I've been searching for a long time.
Any one knows what's up ?

A pizza for whoever finds the right fix :D

Comment: Upon further investigation (checking the /.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/check_rqs file), it looks like the problem is my ant setup. However, the ANT_HOME variable looks correct.

Comment: Okay, I fixed my problem. Apparently, ant couldn't find my build.xml file, even though it was right there in my cordova workshop. So I recreate a workshop, and since, everything works. I can finally run my app on my phone ;D

Comment: I had similar issue.

The issue was with the incompatibility of the Ant version with my Java version.

Ant version I have is 1.8.4. Initially, I had JDK 8 - which supports only Ant 1.9 & greater

Therefore, I uninstalled JDK8 and reverted back to JDK7

Yes, I could have rather updated Ant itself. That is also an option. However, I particularly needed Ant1.8